# Extract fields from JSON document embedded in text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, json, text

I have the following line of text, and I would need to extract a few of the fields from the JSON part of the line of text.

```
June 27th 1997, 10:11:52.621 {"serviceId":"00034","AccessKey":"SBCDSCB","trackID":"KOLPSLSLSLL99029283","membersId":"TEST_0002930493","shopperInfo":{"emailid":"test.ooo4@yahoo.com"},"parkid":{"parkssID":"carrier-park"},"cartinfo":{"checkType":"preorder","detailsmetis":"card","currency":"US","grosscount":"10","reedeem":".00","discount":".00","tokenvalue":{"token":"11102020392023920920393993","bin":"00000000","digit":"0000","expirationDate":"202209","price":"10"}},"cartdetails":[{"dones":[{"donesnames":"test","price":"003","qunt":"1"}]}]}
```

The output I required is below:

```
serviceId,trackID,currency,grosscount 
00034,KOLPSLSLSLL99029283,US,10
```

Please suggest the way to get the above results.

I tried using the `awk` command and some `sed` related queries but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jq`:

```
echo "serviceId,trackID,currency,grosscount"
cut -d' ' -f5- < file \
| jq -r '[.serviceId, .trackID,.cartinfo.currency,.cartinfo.grosscount] | @csv'
```

Instead of `@csv`, which adds quotes around the fields, you can also use `paste`:

```
echo "serviceId,trackID,currency,grosscount"
cut -d' ' -f5- < file \
| jq -r '.serviceId, .trackID,.cartinfo.currency,.cartinfo.grosscount' \
| paste -sd,
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the JSON is identical in structure to the embedded JSON document from [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/704700/116858), we can use [the same `jq` command that I presented there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704705/116858):

```bash
jq -r '
    [ "serviceId", "trackID", "currency", "grosscount" ],
    [ .serviceId, .trackID, .cartinfo.currency, .cartinfo.grosscount ] |
    @csv'
```

The only thing missing here is something that would strip off the non-JSON data before the first `{` on the line.  We can do this with `sed`:

```bash
sed 's/^[^{]*//' file |
jq -r '
    [ "serviceId", "trackID", "currency", "grosscount" ],
    [ .serviceId, .trackID, .cartinfo.currency, .cartinfo.grosscount ] |
    @csv'
```

Given the data in the question, this would produce

```
"serviceId","trackID","currency","grosscount"
"00034","KOLPSLSLSLL99029283","US","10"
```