# Extract data from JSON document embedded in another JSON document

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON document that embeds another JSON document.  I need to extract data from the embedded document, but I'm not well versed with JSON or with `jq`.

The following is my input (`guard.json`):

```json
{
  "_index": "test-2021.06.02",
  "_type": "servrd",
  "_id": "ZWUxMDU5MjItOGY2MC00MGI5LWJhZTEtODRhYWQ1YTZhOGIy",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "stream": "stdout",
    "time": "2021-10-02T03:13:52.496705721Z",
    "docker": {
      "container_id": "392923402349320329432h3432k4kj32kfks9s9sdfksdfjkdsjfsh3939322342"
    },
    "kubernetes": {
      "container_name": "test",
      "namespace_name": "dev",
      "pod_name": "test-dev-v004-9s885",
      "container_image": "localhost:80/pg/test:1.19.0",
      "container_image_id": "docker-pullable://localhost:80/pg/test@sha256:2sfdsfsfsfsfdsr3wrewrewc235e728ad1b29baf5af3dfad30c7706e5eda38b6109",
      "pod_id": "ssfsfds-dsfdsfs-fs-sfsfs-sfdsfsdfsewrw",
      "host": "test-jup-node008",
      "labels": {
        "app": "test",
        "cluster": "test-dev",
        "load-balancer-test-dev": "true",
        "stack": "dev",
        "app_kubernetes_io/managed-by": "spinnaker",
        "app_kubernetes_io/name": "test",
        "moniker_spinnaker_io/sequence": "4"
      },
      "min_url": "https://100.400.0.22:443/api",
      "namespace_id": "jajdjsdf-dfse-dsf-koksls-sksjf030292",
      "namespace_labels": {
        "name": "dev"
      }
    },
    "elapsedTime": 39013,
    "message": "TransactionLog",
    "membersId": "TEST_0233203203_030202020303",
    "payload": "{\"serviceId\":\"00343\",\"AccessKey\":\"testdfsolpGS\",\"trackID\":\"KOLPSLSLSLL99029283\",\"membersId\":\"TEST_0233203203_030202020303\",\"shopperInfo\":{\"emailAddress\":\"test.ooo4@yahoo.com\",\"ipAddress\":\"localhost\"},\"parkid\":{\"parkssID\":\"carrier-park\"},\"cartinfo\":{\"checkType\":\"preorder\",\"detailsmetis\":\"card\",\"currency\":\"US\",\"grosscount\":\"10\",\"reedeem\":\".00\",\"Discount\":\".00\",\"tokenvalue\":{\"token\":\"11102020392023920920393993\",\"Bin\":\"00000\",\"digit\":\"0000\",\"expirationDate\":\"202509\",\"price\":\"10\"}},\"cartdetails\":[{\"dones\":[{\"donesnames\":\"test\",\"price\":\"003\",\"quan\":\"1\"}]}]}",
    "requestDate": "2021-10-02T03:13:12.541207804Z",
    "requestId": "12321321wes-sfsfdsf-snnm79887-029299",
    "finalToClient": "{\"finalType\":\"ok\",\"evaluationMessage\":\"Accept\",\"subMessage\":\"testcallled\",\"score\":0}",
    "serviceId": 00343,
    "timestamp": "2021-10-02T03:13:51.951+00:00",
    "@timestamp": "2021-10-02T03:13:52.621643399+00:00"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-10-02T03:13:52.621Z"
    ],
    "requestDate": [
      "2021-10-02T03:13:12.541Z"
    ],
    "timestamp": [
      "2021-10-02T03:13:51.951Z"
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "kubernetes.labels.app": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@test@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1654139632621
  ]
}
```

I need output in CSV format, similar to this:

```
serviceId, trackID, currency, grosscount
00343,KOLPSLSLSLL99029283,US,10
```

Answer (score 9):

Your question is about extracting certain information stored in a JSON document embedded as a JSON string (`._source.payload`) in another JSON document.

To get at the JSON document with your data, we first need to unwrap the document from its host document:

```bash
jq -r '._source.payload' guard.json
```

Given the example in your question, this would give us something *equivalent of*

```json
{
  "serviceId": "00343",
  "AccessKey": "testdfsolpGS",
  "trackID": "KOLPSLSLSLL99029283",
  "membersId": "TEST_0233203203_030202020303",
  "shopperInfo": {
    "emailAddress": "test.ooo4@yahoo.com",
    "ipAddress": "localhost"
  },
  "parkid": {
    "parkssID": "carrier-park"
  },
  "cartinfo": {
    "checkType": "preorder",
    "detailsmetis": "card",
    "currency": "US",
    "grosscount": "10",
    "reedeem": ".00",
    "Discount": ".00",
    "tokenvalue": {
      "token": "11102020392023920920393993",
      "Bin": "00000",
      "digit": "0000",
      "expirationDate": "202509",
      "price": "10"
    }
  },
  "cartdetails": [
    {
      "dones": [
        {
          "donesnames": "test",
          "price": "003",
          "quan": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From this, you'd like to pick out `.serviceId`, `.trackID`, `.cartinfo.currency`, and `.cartinfo.grosscount` as CSV, with headers.

We can do this like so:

```bash
jq -r '._source.payload' guard.json |
jq -r '
    [ "serviceId", "trackID", "currency", "grosscount" ],
    [ .serviceId, .trackID, .cartinfo.currency, .cartinfo.grosscount ] |
    @csv'
```

The second `jq` command is what extracts the information from the embedded JSON document.  The first array is simply an array of header strings, while the second array is what extracts the data for each column.  These two arrays are then formatted and outputted as CSV using the `@csv` operator.

You could also do this with a single invocation of `jq` by using `fromjson` on the payload (the embedded JSON document):

```bash
jq -r '._source.payload | fromjson |
    [ "serviceId", "trackID", "currency", "grosscount" ],
    [ .serviceId, .trackID, .cartinfo.currency, .cartinfo.grosscount ] |
    @csv' guard.json
```

With the data in the question, this would produce

```
"serviceId","trackID","currency","grosscount"
"00343","KOLPSLSLSLL99029283","US","10"
```

---

Added bits (October 2022):

Using `jq` to extract the embedded payload, by then Miller to create the resulting CSV:

```bash
$ jq -r ._source.payload file | mlr --j2c cut -f serviceId,trackID,cartinfo:currency,cartinfo:grosscount then label serviceId,trackID,currency,grosscount
serviceId,trackID,currency,grosscount
00343,KOLPSLSLSLL99029283,US,10
```